# preventDefault enter key event without preventing scrolling

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, dom-events, keydown

I want to prevent default actions except scrolling. When I have added `e.preventDefault` in `keyDown` event (<kbd>Enter</kbd> key) it also prevents browser from scrolling. I want to prevent actions on enter key press except scrolling. Is there any way to distinguish between enter key event and scroll? Or can we partially prevent default actions where scroll should work and other actions are prevented. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
document.getElementById('textBox').addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            // Cancel the default action, if needed
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

I have added `preventDefault` in enter action. For some reason I must add this line to code but this is also preventing my page from scrolling.
I want to keep `preventDefault` but my page should scroll. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well?

Comment: What do you mean by scroll? Pressing enter key shouldn't scroll your page. You can't even scroll the page with arrow key while focused to a `<input type="text">`.

Comment: fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/shrads7789/ekwbdjm8/1/

Comment: @josephting pressing enter key must scroll my page but should prevent all other default actions on enter.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new line to textarea whenever event is triggered.

```js
document.getElementById('textBox').addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var cursor= this.selectionEnd;
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, cursor) + '\n' + 
    this.value.substring(cursor);
    this.selectionEnd = cursor+1;
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea style="height:200px;width:300px" id="textBox"></textarea>
```

**Note:** I noticed OP is using `contenteditable` in this case. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/uhbe2tzw/) is a fork of OP's JSFiddle. I have made few changes with making different element editable because that seemed more appropriate.

Comment: I have a ContentEditable DIv and not the textArea.

Comment: @Shrads I have added a fork of your fiddle in note with that implementation.

Comment: I don't understand the question, I actually want to prevent the scroll on enter, when you scroll move up with arrow keys and then press enter, it jumps, this solve that jump issue.